# How to combine multiple rows after cross join in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following query in BigQuery:

```
SELECT employees.*
wp.* 

FROM `employees` employees
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(employee.workperiods) wp
where employee_id = '12345' and
wp.type = 'fulltime'
```

this unfortunately returns multiple rows for the same employee, with the only difference being one of the fields in the `employee.workperiods` nested structure

I would like to combine all those rows into one, and just concatenate the strings in the (almost duplicate) rows.

I thought about doing `string_agg` but then I need to group by every field I select, and there are a *lot* of fields I am selecting, I would prefer not to have to group by all of them.

Is there some other way around this with a subquery or something else?

Data currently looks like this:

```
employee_id, name, location, email,    shift_location ..... 
12345,       sam,  NY,       sam@g.co, "city"
12345,       sam,  NY,       sam@g.co, "suburb1 suburb2"
12345,       sam,  NY,       sam@g.co, "store1 store2"
98765,       john, TX,       john@g.co, "store5 store6"
98765,       john, TX,       john@g.co, "city1 city2"
```

I want the data to look like:

```
employee_id, name, location, email,    shift_location ..... 
12345,       sam,  NY,       sam@g.co, "city suburb1 suburb2 store1 store2"
98765,       john, TX,       john@g.co, "store5 store6 city1 city2"
```

Comment: Can you update your post with sample data and expected output?

Comment: Just added examples

Answer (score 0):

Dont have source data schema but inferring from what you posted maybe something like that:

```
SELECT
  e.name,
  e.employee_id,
  wp.location,
  wp.email,
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(wp.shift_location),' ') AS shift_locations
FROM
  `employees` AS e,
  UNNEST(e.workperiods) AS wp
GROUP BY
  1, 2, 3, 4
;
```